# How to centered output data across "|" in everything column in terminal?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-terminal, unix-utils

I want to align output in terminal by the following command:

```
xlscat -C 1,2,9,12 file.xls
```

I get output like this:

```
string 1     | 1000 | 1 | text
...
string 100 | 61 | 109 | number
...
string 1000 | 3477 | 12 | something
```

I'd like to align output of an embedded tool of UNIX, like this:

```
string 1    | 1000 |  1  | text
...
string 100  |  61  | 109 | number
...
string 1000 | 3477 |  1  | something
```

I tried to use `column(1) -t`, but it did not help me.

Is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: I think your actual output isn't rendering correctly - there are more spaces in raw text than displayed. Please use a code block to make sure it looks exactly like it should. ([edit] the question)

Comment: In what way does `column -t` fail to meet your requirements? The example you provided looks reasonably aligned after filtering through `column -t`. I can imagine data that wouldn't, but it's not in the question. Is it about numbers not being centered? Please be specific.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, yes, not centered. Idk how to  fix it. Sorry, I speak English  very bad

Comment: Please [edit] and place your requirement(s) in the question. You should state explicitly: data in the second and in the third column should be centered.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, see. Now good?